# php array multidimensional count and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array which looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [Time] => 00 
    [Activity] => Surfing 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [Time] => 00 
    [Activity] => Surfing 
    ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [Time] => 00 
    [Activity] => Kayaking 
    ) 
[3] => Array ( 
    [Time] => 15 
    [Activity] => Surfing 
    ) 
)
```

But I'm struggling to get the counts I need in the right format. Basically what I wish to achieve is a count for each 'Activity' within each 'Time'. So for example I would like to output something like this:

```
Time:00 - Surfing 2; Kayaking 1
Time:15 - Surfing 1; Swimming 2
Time:45 - Surfing 1
```

etc.

I'm not sure if I should be looking at count functions or maybe foreach inside a foreach? But it has me stumped. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: I fail to see how the input could lead to the desired output...

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @jeroen and pranav m.s - please see answers below ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure "Swimming" and "45" will magicallly appear like that ;-)

Comment: Ok, so the array was an example and so was the output - i.e. there can be multiple activities and times. The less pedantic people here got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt appears to work:

```
$array = array(
    array("time"=>"00", "Activity"=>"Surfing"), 
    array("time"=>"00", "Activity"=>"Surfing"), 
    array("time"=>"00", "Activity"=>"Kayaking"), 
    array("time"=>"15", "Activity"=>"Surfing")
    );

$sortedArr = array();

/* first we need to sort the array so that we have a new array that is formatted with the time value as the key */

foreach($array as $arr) {

    $timeVal      = $arr['time'];
    $activityName = $arr['Activity'];

    /* if there is a time and activity key already set then we'll increment the count. Otherwise, we'll set it as 1 */

    if(isset($sortedArr[$timeVal][$activityName])) {
        $sortedArr[$timeVal][$activityName]++;
    } else {
        $sortedArr[$timeVal][$activityName] = 1;
    }
}

/* now we've re-ordered things, we'll build the output and then echo it out */

$output = '';
foreach($sortedArr as $key=>$vals) {
    $output.= 'Time:'.$key.' - ';

    foreach($vals as $activityName=>$activityCount) {
        $output .= $activityName.' '.$activityCount.';'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: This one seems to work best and is most flexible so I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad you liked my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array_list as $key => $val)
{
     if(isset($new_array[$val[$time]][$val['Activity']]))
     {
         $new_array[$val[$time]][$val['Activity']] += 1;
     }
     else
     {
         $new_array[$val[$time]][$val['Activity']] = 1;
     }
}
```

next step what ever you loop again the new_array to show all array the new array for every unique time its your choice, 
or if you need it to compare within new data you just can directly access the new array as ex below

```
echo $new_array['00']['Surfing']
```

then you will get the count for time 00 for surfing

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$timings = [];
foreach ($array as $activity) {
    $timings[$activity['Activity']][] = $activity['Time'];
}

$surfing = array_sum($timings['Surfing']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If structure of nested arrays will not change
You can do this:

```
$array = [
    [
        "Time" => "00",
        "Activity" => "Surfing"
    ],
    [
        "Time" => "00",
        "Activity" => "Surfing"
    ],
    [
        "Time" => "00",
        "Activity" => "Kayaking"
    ],
    [
        "Time" => "15",
        "Activity" => "Surfing"
    ]
];
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $time = $value["Time"];
    $activity = $value["Activity"];
    if (!isset($result[$time])) {
        $result[$time] = [];
    }
    if (!isset($result[$time][$activity])) {
        $result[$time][$activity] = 0;
    }
    $result[$time][$activity]++;
}
```

End `print_r($result)` return this:

```
Array
(
[00] => Array
    (
        [Surfing] => 2
        [Kayaking] => 1
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [Surfing] => 1
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but here is my code. 
Outputs exactly what you wanted.

```
<?php

//mockup
$activities = array( 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "00",
                        "Activity" => "Surfing",
                  ), 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "00",
                        "Activity" => "Surfing",
                  ), 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "00",
                        "Activity" => "Kayaking", 
                  ), 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "15", 
                        "Activity" => "Surfing"
                    ), 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "15", 
                        "Activity" => "Swimming"
                    ), 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "15", 
                        "Activity" => "Swimming"
                    ), 
                array( 
                        "Time"     => "45", 
                        "Activity" => "Surfing"
                    )  
);

$reordered = array();

foreach($activities as $activity)
{
    foreach($activity as $key => $value)
    {
        //echo "$key => $value <br>";

        if($key=="Time")
        {
            $tmp_time = $value;
        }
        elseif($key=="Activity")
        {
            if(!isset($reordered[$tmp_time][$value]))
                $reordered[$tmp_time][$value]=1;
            else
            $reordered[$tmp_time][$value]++;
        }
    }
}


//var_dump($reordered);

$output='';

foreach($reordered as $key => $arr)
{
    $output.='Time:' . $key . ' - ';

    foreach($arr as $activityName=>$activityCount) 
    {
        $output.= $activityName.' '.$activityCount.'; ';
    }
    $output = rtrim($output,"; ");
    $output.=PHP_EOL;
}



echo $output;

/*

Time:00 - Surfing 2; Kayaking 1
Time:15 - Surfing 1; Swimming 2
Time:45 - Surfing 1

*/
```